# How to Connect this Crocodile Clips to my Multimeter?

Tags: connector, multimeter

I got crocodile clips with my multimeter, but no cable with them. The tips of the probes I have, do not fit into the plug on the crocodile clips.

[image: Crocodile Clip]

**How do I connect them to my multimeter? What kind of cable do I need?**

I assume this is some kind of standard connector, I searched around but did not find anything useful. Seems I just lack the exact name of this kind of connector.

*Update:* The multimeter is a *Testo 760-3* with the default probes. They have a small ~2mm conic tip.

Here a picture of the probe tip:

[image: Probe Tip]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: Can you put the model of your multimeter (or at least the brand). The female port behind the crocodile clips seems to be designed to accept something.

Comment: Either get 2mm "banana plug" connectors or remove the 2mm->4mm adapter and get regular 4mm "banana plug" connectors.

Comment: Have you tried sticking the test prod needle point into the round ferrule at the end opposite to the jaws? Does the point fit into it and stay firmly attached?

Comment: @LeonHeller:  What forum would such a question belong in?

Comment: Are you assuming that everyone magically knows what meter and probes you have, or are you assuming that every meter and probes work exactly the same?

Comment: You will have to give us more details concerning the multimeter and the probes in particular that you are using.  Where did you get the clips?

Comment: @leonheller the use of Electronics tools is on topic........

Comment: Looks like the end of the clip can be pulled out. I'm guessing that a wire, likely 22 awg, goes into the hole, then gets pressed back into the clip.

Comment: I have a similar accessory for my multimeter (Agilent 1272) and it "works" by plugging the probe inside the hole as FiddyOhm has noted. It clicks and locks in place.

Comment: Some probes have banana-plug style springs on them. It looks to me that you need a pair of those, but really, why don´t you just address the question to the place you bought the meter from in the first place. They should be able to answer your question better than anyone here, especially since you haven´t given us much to go on, eg make and model of the meter.

Comment: Does the end of the crocodile clip plug directly into the 4mm sockets on the front of the meter?

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific about the equipment, I assumed there is some kind of standard for this connectors and the actual brand does not matter. The Multimeter is a Testo 760-3, which not a very known brand. The probes I have are the ones came with the Multimeter. These probes have no banana-plug style endings.

Comment: There is no part which can be removed from the plug, it is welded into place. The outer diameter is 5mm, the inner diameter is ~2.3mm.

Comment: @FiddyOhm Yes I tried sticking the test probe into end, it is too short and its diameter is too small to stay attached.

Comment: @canadiancyborg The multimeter is a Testo 760-3, the crocodile clips are from Testo as well and have the product number 0590 0009. I Added an image with the probe tips, these are the probes which came with the multimeter.

Comment: @F.Bloggs You are absolutely right, but I got no information from there. Also found nothing useful on the internet.

Comment: @HandyHowie No, I tried this, the diameter does not match the probe cable connectors.

Comment: @Janka There is no part which can be removed. I added more details about the multimeter and the probe to my question.

Comment: @12Lapointep The multimeter is a Testo 760-3, the crocodile clips are from Testo as well and have the product number 0590 0009. See the picture I added to the question to size relations.

Comment: @Flovdis -- do you have any other probe without the insulation? My multimeter came with 2 pairs, insulated and non-insulated tips, the non-insulated one is the one that fits. p.s.: posting 8 comments in a row does not help your question to be understandable.

Comment: @WesleyLee No, I just got one pair with the tips as shown. I will check if there are other without insulation. And yes, I realised I should have merged everything into one single comment.

Comment: I just googled your meter and the photos show probes with the little banana-plug style ends. You may have been given the wrong probes. Or - does the insulation at the top of your probes come off? Check that it doesn´t pull or screw off.

Comment: @Flovdis It looks like the isolation of the probe can come out.  I would try that first.  Secondly, I would make sure this clip on is Type K.

Comment: @12Lapointep The isolation of the probe is all one piece and can not be removed.

Comment: Does your multimeter have 4mm sockets? If yes, get two cables with a banana plug, and de-solder these non-matching adapters from the clips. The 4mm banana plugs should fit into the new opening perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the clip is intended to fit over the probe but it is being stopped from doing so by the plastic sheidling on the probe tip.

On some probes the plastic shielding on the tip is removable. It may be that you need to remove it to use the croc clip. It may also be that the vendor screwed up and shippped clips that were not compatible with the test leads.

Answer (score 0):

The probes for my meter look something like that - the plastic over the metal probe just pulls off - then the probe tip should fit into the clip.

Answer (score 0):

The [instructions](https://www.testo.com/en-US/Parameters/Electrical/Voltage/Crocodile-clips/p/0590%200009) for those clips state

> Simply put the measuring cables into the crocodile clip.

---

I notice that there is a considerable amount of insulation missing from the clips in your photo as compared to the published configuration.

If the leads you show are the [standard ones](https://www.testo.com/en-US/Parameters/Electrical/Voltage/Standard-measuring-cables-%28angled-plug%29/p/0590%200010) then your ones have an additional sleeve on the end - it could be that someone has previously attached the leads to the clips and broken them when trying to remove them.

Answer (score -1):

You can strip a piece of wire at one end and clamp it to the crocodile clip using a bullet crimper tool. The other end probably a banana jack assume that your multimeter accepts it.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that this is the intended usage of that croc clip. The slightly unusual blunt end suggests some intended connectivit